# how to execute a command prompt command in my own console application

Tags: c#, console-application, command-prompt

how can i make my console application window to behave like a command prompt window and execute my command line arguments?

Comment: there are a bunch of resources to be found online for this. Please research before posting here. Also, [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Google first result for `c# console application command line arguments` is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You both misunderstood the question - read again.

Comment: What is *command prompt command*? What is *behave like a command prompt window*? Do you want to pass command line arguments to your console application or what?

Comment: @AmirAbiri I read again. I don't think I misunderstood the fact that the OP didn't research his or her question.

Comment: @WimOmbelets I don't think writing a shell wrapper is as trivial as you present it, and it's a question worth asking IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName               = "cmd.exe",
                CreateNoWindow         = true,
                UseShellExecute        = false,
                RedirectStandardInput  = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError  = true
            }
        };

        proc.Start();

        new Thread(() => ReadOutputThread(proc.StandardOutput)).Start();
        new Thread(() => ReadOutputThread(proc.StandardError)).Start();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(">> ");
            var line = Console.ReadLine();
            proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }

    private static void ReadOutputThread(StreamReader streamReader)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

The basics are:

- open cmd.exe process and capture all three streams (in, out, err)
- pass input from outside in
- read output and transfer to your own output.

The "Redirect" options are important - otherwise you can't use the process' respective streams.

The code above is very basic, but you can improve on it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this

```
var command = "dir";
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```